# Boolean Full-text returns empty set

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using boolean full-text search on a table. This is my database:

```
 CREATE TABLE `data_mahasiswa` (
  `nim` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `nama` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `kom` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `kota` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ipk` float NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `data_mahasiswa`
--

INSERT INTO `data_mahasiswa` (`nim`, `nama`, `kom`, `kota`, `ipk`, `email`) VALUES
('181401002', 'Randy Heksadesianto', 'B', 'Medan', 3.87647, 'randyheksadesianto@yahoo.com'),
('181401003', 'Nur Azizah Harahap', 'A', 'Binjai', 3.72941, 'Hellosooj@gmail.com'),
('181401004', 'Istikanah Wulandari', 'C', 'Asahan', 3.71176, 'Istikanahw@gmail.com'),
('181401005', 'Chyntia Wilhelmine Nainggolan', 'B', 'Batu Bara', 3.79412, 'chyntiawilhelmine@gmail.com');
```

I'm trying to query data with kom "B" in them, I've tried:

```
select * from data_mahasiswa where match(kom) against ('+B' in boolean mode);
```

But it returns an empty set `Empty set (0.001 sec)`
There should be a result,as there are 2 row with "B" as kom

How can I fix this? Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It's probably not working because Full Text search does WORD searches.  Since "B" is not a word in any of the rows, there are no matches.  Does changing your WHERE clause to the following work for you? WHERE kom LIKE '%B%'

Comment: Russ I've tried as u suggested,it still doesn't work
Thx for answering